# I want to code that will search if file exist, if it exist then it will open that record else it will create new

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am new to coding. I created a program in VB.net with database in MS access
I want to make a textbox which will work as both search bar and add new. When the user enter text and move to next textbox then function will search that if that prog no. exist it would show that record otherwise it will create new. 
The problem with this code is that while adding new record it changes the prog no. of last opened record.
Here's the code

```
Private Sub progno_enterpress(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles progno.LostFocus

    prgnum = progno.Text
    If progno.Text = "" Then
        Call notfound()
        Exit Sub

    Else
        Table1BindingSource.Filter = "(Prgno Like '" & prgnum & "')"
        If Table1BindingSource.Count <> 0 Then

                With DataGridView1
                    .DataSource = Table1BindingSource
                End With

                Table1BindingSource.EndEdit()
            Exit Sub
        Else
            Table1BindingSource.Filter = Nothing
            Table1BindingSource.AddNew()
            Exit Sub
        End If
```

Comment: If this were VBA in Access, I would first move to new record on form and use textbox BeforeUpdate event to validate input. I would also probably use a combobox instead of textbox.